# How do I add a service to an AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a trying to add a service to my Angular app.
But everything breaks when I add Session to the controller:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CustomersCtrl' is not a function, got string
```

As you might have guessed, I'm just starting to learn Angular. Some start help would be nice. :-)

**app/assets/javascripts/angular-app/controllers/customers.js.coffee**

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller 'CustomersCtrl', 'helloWorldFromService', 
    ($scope, Restangular, helloWorldFromService) ->
      console.log('hello': helloWorldFromService.sayHello())
```

**app/assets/javascripts/angular-app/services/hello.js**

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .service('helloWorldFromService', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
    return "Hello, World!"
    };
  });
```

Comment: what does this look like when cofee transalates it? You only have one string argument for array but 3 arguments in function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller must look like this (with minification)

```
 .controller('CustomersCtrl', ['$scope','Restangular','helloWorldFromService', 
function($scope, Restangular, helloWorldFromService) {
            }
         ]
    );
```